# AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB) with IPv6 dual-stack did not support UDP listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nlb

Is there any workarounds with AWS NLB to support UDP listeners with IPv6?
I need dual-stack NLB (supports IPv6) and add UDP listener to this NLB. But it's not supported by AWS. Does any have this issue? What can be done at this point. I know that I can create EC2 instance with IPV6 support and deploy here UDP service but in this case domain name will be different and it's not acceptable. Domain name should be the same as dual-stack NLB.

AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB) with IPv6 dual-stack IP address type and UDP listeners workaround.
AWS plans to implement this feature.